# Need answers regarding MongoDB set up on local machine for lot of data

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, requirements

I have data more than 200gb and it is in JSON and CSV format and more than 300millian rows (documents).

I want to store it in MongoDB Database. I want to know that what requirement of the machine to handle this process like store and retrieval and manipulation of data. Also what time it would take to search data from whole data?

Comment: You could use something like Apache Drill to just query the existing JSON or CSV... Do you explicitly require Mongo?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I want to compare and perform some filters and produce output and also want to use the web interface to manipulate data on the localhost that is why I require mongo also need to analyze the data.

Comment: One suggestion is that：avoid using mongodb to do aggregation on large data sets, it is slow and has memory limitation

Comment: I do not need to aggregate documents I just need to compare one data set with another this will I can do by creating the query and if results are returned then do the procedure on it and store it

Comment: Okay, I'm just pointing out that picking Mongo simply because it might be able to query the data might be too focused on one technology. For example, I'm sure people use Postgres or Mysql to query and do aggregations on similar data. Drill could be ran as a JDBC server too, for online applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, technical choice depends on your data structure and how to use these data. Below answer **assumed you store all the data into a single collection in a single mongodb instance in a single machine**.

---

I did an experiment in the past to test the performance of mongodb with large data. I will share the result to you.

### Data volume

- Amount of data: 1 Billion
- document format: 4 fields(ObjectID + Int + String + Date) ~ 200Bytes/document
- All documents are stored into one collection

### Hardware

- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10Ghz(4 cores)
- RAM: 32GB
- Disk: 2TB LSI MRSASRoMB-8i SCSI Disk Device

### Software

- OS: Redhat Sever6.4-X86-64 with Ext4
- Mongodb: 3.2 x64 (engine: wireTiger, cacheSize set to 28GB)

### Test result

#### Insert performance

Before index creation: No additional index(only default _id index)
After index creation: Add one more index on the string field

```
╔══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║                      ║ Before index creation ║ After index creation ║
╠══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ Single thread insert ║ 656/s - 746/s         ║ 534/s - 712/s        ║
║ 10 Threads insert    ║ 3817/s - 3964/s       ║ 3306/s - 3389/s      ║
╚══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

#### Query performance

Query by the string field.

```
╔═══════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║                   ║ Before index creation ║ After index creation ║
╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ Return 1 document ║ 1268904 ms            ║ 15 ms                ║
╚═══════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

#### Build index

If build index on string field after already 1 Billion documents in the collection, **it takes ~3 hours to finish.**

#### RAM consumption

In the insert test, when all the cahce(28GB) runs out, the insert speed will drop.

### Conclusion

1. No big different between before index & after index in insert performance.(In my condition, not sure when created a lot of indexes)
2. Mongodb tend to use as much as RAM it can, if you have large hot data, you'd better provide large RAM to it.
3. If built good index, then the query performance is good at Billion data level.
4. Build index on large data will cost you a lot of time.